# How to fill blank cells with data from an API in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a list of **BIN** (*Bank Identification Number*) with the following columns: Bin, Brand, Type, Category, Issuer, Country and Alpha with more than **500k** lines.

As it is a very outdated dB, it does not contain updated information, such as new banks, different categories and brands.

Some of the cells in each row are not filled, and, as it is a list with a considerably large number of rows, I would like to know if it is possible to fill these rows automatically through **APIs** in JSON format. I did some research and saw that it is "possible" to do this with `VBA` however, I would like something more practical, that I can undo in case of errors, such as filling in with incorrect values, etc., something more focused on functions.

> <sup>Below is the spreadsheet:</sup>[image]

One of the sites that I will consult this information to feed my spreadsheet is the [bins.su](http://bins.su/) and [binlist.net](https://binlist.net/)

It is worth mentioning that, my goal is not to fill in all the cells, as not all bin numbers have this public information, so I fill this information with "N/A".

---

#### The JSON response structures are as follows

The only keys of interest to me are: *scheme, type, brand, country[name], country[alpha2]*

```json
{
  "number": {
    "length": 16,
    "luhn": true
  },
  "scheme": "visa",
  "type": "debit",
  "brand": "Visa/Dankort",
  "prepaid": false,
  "country": {
    "numeric": "208",
    "alpha2": "DK",
    "name": "Denmark",
    "emoji": "",
    "currency": "DKK",
    "latitude": 56,
    "longitude": 10
  },
  "bank": {
    "name": "Jyske Bank",
    "url": "www.jyskebank.dk",
    "phone": "+4589893300",
    "city": "Hjørring"
  }
}
```

Is this possible? or will I have to resort to other applications or scripts?

Comment: If you know they provide APIs serving the desired content as JSON, and you can afford it/it is free, any limitations on rate are bearable, the answer is likely yes.  Common VBA libraries for interacting with APIs tend to struggle/fail with sending JSON to endpoints but otherwise there is usually a way. Looks at the API docs, have a play. Write the appropriate branched code to implement your logic, such as missing items. Are you going to have implement a try this endpoint and if not found then try this endpoint approach? etc.... Currently, this post is too broad so voting to close.

Comment: Do you have scope to use another language (like Python) to do the talking to the API? Python + openpyxl or Python + xlWings and this is very straightforward.

Comment: have a examples?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure this is possible with API calls, but you haven't provided the API details for the `bins.su` site.

That doesn't matter too much as you can easily parse the data from the POST response itself. The only issue would be that you don't receive exactly the same data as that returned by the `binlist` site.

The `binlist` returned JSON object is simple enough not to need to convert it to a VBA entity - you can just extract the items from the JSON string.

The 'binlist' API has a limit of 10 per minute, so you'll need to throttle your code if you're calling over 500k items. I don't know about the other site.

For the code, you 'll need to reference Tools->References->Microsoft WinHTTP Servicses v5.1 (or whatever version you have).

To keep things easy to read, I've created a class module called *clsBIN* that looks like below. You'll need to create this class module (Insert->Class Module):

```
Option Explicit

Public Number As Long
Public Brand As String
Public Scheme As String
Public BinType As String
Public Category As String
Public Issuer As String
Public CountryAlpha As String
Public Country As String
```

Then in a Module, just use the code below. You'll see there are two functions, one for each web request, and a simple procedure to that iterates the BINs and populates the empty fields. This procedure only calls the `bin.su` function - you'll need to add throttling if you want to use the other one:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RunMe()
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim bin As clsBIN
    Dim hasEmpties As Boolean
    
    With Sheet1
        v = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 7).Value2
    End With
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing " & i & " of " & UBound(v, 1) & "..."
        hasEmpties = False
        For j = 1 To UBound(v, 2)
            If IsEmpty(v(i, j)) Then
                hasEmpties = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If hasEmpties Then
            Set bin = FindBINfromBinsSu(CLng(v(i, 1)))
            If Not bin Is Nothing Then
                With bin
                    If IsEmpty(v(i, 2)) Then Sheet1.Range("B" & i + 1).Value = IIf(.Brand = "", "N/A", .Brand)
                    If IsEmpty(v(i, 3)) Then Sheet1.Range("C" & i + 1).Value = IIf(.BinType = "", "N/A", .BinType)
                    If IsEmpty(v(i, 4)) Then Sheet1.Range("D" & i + 1).Value = IIf(.Category = "", "N/A", .Category)
                    If IsEmpty(v(i, 5)) Then Sheet1.Range("E" & i + 1).Value = IIf(.Issuer = "", "N/A", .Issuer)
                    If IsEmpty(v(i, 6)) Then Sheet1.Range("F" & i + 1).Value = IIf(.Country = "", "N/A", .Country)
                    If IsEmpty(v(i, 7)) Then Sheet1.Range("G" & i + 1).Value = IIf(.CountryAlpha = "", "N/A", .CountryAlpha)
                End With
            End If
        End If
        DoEvents
    Next
    Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub

Public Function FindBINfromBinList(num As Long) As clsBIN
    Dim req As WinHttpRequest
    Dim hdrs As Variant
    Dim p1(4) As Long, p2(4) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim str As String
    
    On Error GoTo EH
    Set req = New WinHttpRequest
    With req
        'Construct the post request.
        .SetTimeouts 60000, 60000, 60000, 60000
        .Open "GET", "https://lookup.binlist.net/" & num, False
        .SetRequestHeader "Accept-Version", "3"
        
        'Send the request.
        .Send
        str = .ResponseText
    End With
    
    'Check for result headers.
    hdrs = Array("scheme", "type", "brand", "alpha2", "name")
    For i = 0 To 4
        p1(i) = InStr(str, Chr(34) & hdrs(i) & Chr(34))
        If p1(i) = 0 Then Exit Function
        p1(i) = InStr(p1(i), str, ":")
        p2(i) = InStr(p1(i), str, ",")
        If p2(i) = 0 Then Exit Function
    Next
    
    'Extract the results.
    Set FindBINfromBinList = New clsBIN
    With FindBINfromBinList
        .Number = num
        .Scheme = Mid(str, p1(0) + 2, p2(0) - p1(0) - 3)
        .BinType = Mid(str, p1(1) + 2, p2(1) - p1(1) - 3)
        .Brand = Mid(str, p1(2) + 2, p2(2) - p1(2) - 3)
        .CountryAlpha = Mid(str, p1(3) + 2, p2(3) - p1(3) - 3)
        .Country = Mid(str, p1(4) + 2, p2(4) - p1(4) - 3)
    End With
    Exit Function
    
EH:
    'Handle errors.
End Function

Private Function FindBINfromBinsSu(num As Long) As clsBIN
    Dim req As WinHttpRequest
    Dim p1 As Long, p2 As Long
    Dim str As String
    Dim t() As String
    Dim s() As String
    
    On Error GoTo EH
    Set req = New WinHttpRequest
    With req
        'Construct the post request - amend headers as required.
        .SetTimeouts 60000, 60000, 60000, 60000
        .Open "POST", "http://bins.su/", False
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.80 Safari/537.36 Edg/98.0.1108.50"
        .SetRequestHeader "Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
        
        'Send the request.
        .Send "action=searchbins&bins=" & num & "&bank=&country="
        
        'Extract the results table.
        p1 = InStr(.ResponseText, "<div id=" & Chr(34) & "result" & Chr(34) & ">")
        If p1 = 0 Then Exit Function
        p1 = InStr(p1, .ResponseText, "<table>")
        If p1 = 0 Then Exit Function
        p1 = p1 + Len("<table>")
        p2 = InStr(p1, .ResponseText, "</table>")
        If p2 = 0 Then Exit Function
        str = Mid(.ResponseText, p1, p2 - p1)
    End With
    
    'Remove the start tags.
    str = Replace(str, "<tr>", "")
    str = Replace(str, "<td>", "")
    
    'Create an array of table rows.
    t = Split(str, "</tr>")
    If UBound(t) < 1 Then Exit Function
    
    'Create an array of tablerow items - used the second array element as first is headers.
    s = Split(t(1), "</td>")
    If UBound(s) < 5 Then Exit Function
    
    'Return the data.
    Set FindBINfromBinsSu = New clsBIN
    With FindBINfromBinsSu
        .Number = num
        .Brand = s(2)
        .BinType = s(3)
        .Category = s(4)
        .Issuer = s(5)
        .CountryAlpha = s(1)
    End With
    Exit Function
    
EH:
    'Handle errors.
End Function
```

Comment: excuse my ignorance, but will this module feed empty cells automatically? according to each category? country, alpha, brand, among others.

Comment: No, it retrieves the BIN data for any specified BIN. You just need to iterate each row in your data and, for any BIN that has missing data, call one or other of these functions. You'd then either populate the missing items or process the data however you want to identify your N/A case.

Comment: can you guide me to do this in excel? for my knowledge is very shallow, but let me see if I understand. The functions included in this module that you developed, would I be able to invoke them in the excel formula bar? or not?

Comment: You'd be better writing it in VBA because of the throttling problem with the API. I can show you how to iterate, but you need to update your question. We need to see the name of the sheet and what column each data item belongs to . Are you modifying the original sheet or writing to a new sheet? What decides which of the two websites you use for the BIN look up? I have to say, if you're not experience with VBA,, then you're better giving this to VBA specialist.

Comment: In my case, I would like to feed the same sheet, in different columns, i.e. the brand, type, category, issuer, country and alpha column. For the sake of conscience, would it be necessary for me to provide the xlsx file here?

Comment: No, just modify the image in your question to show where the additional columns. I can easily rewrite the code to show you how to iterate. I'll just use the bin.su site to avoid the throttling for now. Just to be clear, this isn't a code-writing service, so you'll need to contact a professional if you want a robust solution.

Comment: What would the "additional columns" be? just to see if we're talking about the same thing? because the only columns present, just for identification purposes, are the ones I mentioned to you, which by the way are in A1, B1, C1, D1, E1, F1, G1. Note: regarding the code rewrite, feel free to do it, it will be of great help to me! and first of all thank you for the support you are giving me!

Comment: Iteration added. It'll take a while to run this on 500k rows.

Comment: I get the following error when running "compilation error: variable not defined" in "Public Sub RunMe()"